# Why does glibc store the return value of a system call into errno

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, glibc

I read that when a system call fails the kernel returns the corresponding error number explaining the failure. Why is this error not directly returned to user applications?

Why does glibc store this in global `errno` variable? What is the advantage of doing this?

Comment: Because glibc follows POSIX. Are you really asking why POSIX says to do that?

Comment: Yes. Benefit of storing it in a separate variable.

Comment: It's the subject of debate, but it boils down to "historical reasons'.  Early versions of Unix did it — later versions (and standard C and POSIX) all kept it to avoid breaking working code.  The `errno` mechanism has many flaws, especially in modern, multithreaded code.  The POSIX `pthread` library doesn't use `errno`; the functions report the error number directly.  You can find diatribes about `errno` in books such as 
P J Plauger
[The Standard C Library](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131315099) 1992.

Comment: See also the POSIX Rationale on [Error Numbers](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_03) — there's quite a lot there that's relevant.

Comment: Since this is "hidden" at the end of the current answer, I'd like to highlight, that `errno` doesn't have to be a global variable. It can be other things like a macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

The use of `errno` is the subject of debate, but it boils down to "historical reasons". Early versions of Unix did it — later versions (and standard C and POSIX) all kept it to avoid breaking working code. The `errno` mechanism has many flaws, especially in modern, multithreaded code. The POSIX pthread library doesn't use `errno`; the functions report the error number directly. You can find diatribes about `errno` in books such as P J Plauger [The Standard C Library](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131315099) (1992).  It's quite old and describes C90, but much of it remains relevant today.

The POSIX Rationale on [Error Numbers](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_03) has quite a lot of information on the topic.  Note in particular the subsection on 'Alternative Solutions for Per-Thread `errno`'.

Note that old C code might write `extern int errno;` in a source file.  Since multithreading became commonplace, that is incorrect.  The only correct way to get the declaration of `errno` in modern code is `#include <errno.h>`.  This is because the name may be a macro for a 'modifiable lvalue'.  On one system (macOS Catalina 10.15.2), you can find:

```
extern int * __error(void);  // Do not copy this
#define errno (*__error())   // Do not copy this
```

That's quite different from `extern int errno;`.  Note that other systems have different ways of declaring it — you can't copy what I showed into your code and expect it to work.  Include the header; it is simple and reliable (and is the only way to do the job reliably).